# On a step of Marcus' "Number Fields", Theorem 22 Chapter 3

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I've been reading Marcus' Number Fields and there is a step in the proof of Theorem 22 that I can't understand. Specifically, it's about the proof of 22(b).

> **Theorem 22.** Let $K$ and $L$ be number fields, $K\subset L$, let $R=\mathbb{A}\cap K$ (the set of algebraic integers in $K$) and $S=\mathbb{A}\cap L$, and $n=[L:K]$.
>
> (a) For ideals $I$ and $J$ in $R$, $\lVert IJ\rVert=\lVert I\rVert\,\lVert J\rVert$.
>
> (b) Let $I$ be an ideal in $R$. For the $S$-ideal $IS$, $\lVert IS\rVert = \lVert I\rVert^n$.
>
> (c) Let $\alpha\in R$, $\alpha\neq 0$. For the principal ideal $(\alpha)$, $\lVert(\alpha)\rVert = |N_{\mathbb{Q}}^K(\alpha)|$.

Inside the proof of 22(b), Marcus states and proves (well, sort of) a Lemma.

> Lemma: Let $A$ and $B$ be nonzero ideals in a Dedekind domain $R$, with $B\subset A$ and $A\neq B$. Then there exists $\gamma\in K$ such that $\gamma B\subset R$, $\gamma B\not\subset A$.

Then, he applies the Lemma with $A=P$ and $B=(b_1,\ldots,b_{n+1})$. Of course, we want a contradiction and so we assumed that $B$ is a subset of $A$. This is why we can apply the Lemma. But I am having trouble filling in the details. I can't get a contradiction.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset mathematics. Also, the way you've phrased your question it is utterly impossible for anyone that has no access to the book to help you. It would be better if you provide enough information that people without that direct access can understand your question.

Comment: I've added some details, but unfortunately not quite enough for people to know what your issue is without access to the book.

Comment: Thank you for adding the details! Let's hope that someone who read the book will help us out! If not, I'll add even more details.

Comment: Yeah, too much detail needed to know what is going on, but the argument is actually pretty straightforward...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a copy of Marcus with me, so I can fill in some of the details. However, unless you wanted the audience of your post to be limited to those who (i) have access to a copy of the book; and (ii) take the trouble to pull it off the shelf, look up the theorem, and backtrack enough to see what all the symbols mean; then you should try, in the future, to provide enough context in your post so that even those without access may have a shot at understanding the problem and your query about it, and potentially offer help.

Marcus will prove (b) in the special case of $I=P$ a prime ideal, relying on (a) to deduce the general case. Now, $S/PS$ is a vector space over $R/P$, and we want to show it has dimension exactly $n$. First, we show it has dimension *at most* $n$, by showing that any collection of $n+1$ elements is necessarily linearly dependent. To that end, let $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_{n+1} \in S$, and we want to show that their images in $S/PS$ are linearly dependent over $R/P$. We know the original elements are linearly dependent in $L$ over $K$, since $[L:K]=n$. And we know that we can multiply the linear dependence equation by some integer so that all coefficients lie in $R$, rather than in $K$ (this was proven in an exercise in the previous chapter: if $\alpha\in K$, then there exists $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $m\alpha\in R$). This gives us an equation of the form
$$\beta_1\alpha_1+\cdots+\beta_{n+1}\alpha_{n+1} = 0,$$
where $\beta_i\in R$. We want to reduce this modulo $P$, but to prove that we don't have a trivial linear combination after reduction, we need to ensure that not all $\beta_j$ lie in $P$. This is where the Lemma comes in.

If at least one $\beta_j\notin P$, we are done. Assume, however, that we are unlucky enough to have all $\beta_i\in P$. This *could* happen: for example, maybe all of our original $\alpha_i$ are in $P$, and so we pick  all $\beta_j$ in $P$. So we aren't looking for a contradiction. Instead, we want to show we can tweak the linear dependence relation so that the resulting one does  *not* have all coefficients in $P$.

We apply the Lemma with
$A=P$, $B=(\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_{n+1})$, ideals in the Dedekind domain $R$, we have $B\subseteq A$, $A\neq R$ (since it is prime). Let $\gamma\in K$ be guaranteed by the Lemma, so that $\gamma B\subset R$ and $\gamma B\not\subset P$. Now take the original linear dependent equation and multiply through by $\gamma$:
$$0 = \gamma(\beta_1\alpha_1+\cdots+\beta_{n+1}\alpha_{n+1}) = (\gamma\beta_1)\alpha_1+\cdots+(\gamma\beta_{n+1})\alpha_{n+1}.$$
Now notice that since $\gamma B$ is generated by $\gamma\beta_1,\ldots,\gamma\beta_{n+1}$, it *cannot* be the case that all the new coefficients lie in $P$ (since $\gamma B\not\subset P$). Thus, we are now in the situation where not all coefficients lie in $P$, and so reducing modulo $P$ we obtain a nontrivial linear dependence relation between $\overline{\alpha_1},\ldots,\overline{\alpha_{n+1}}$, which is what we wanted to show. This proves that $S/PS$ has dimension at most $n$, as claimed.

Comment: Yeah, that turned out to be very silly..definetely the easiest detail to fill in in the entire proof.. Anyhow..thank you very much and sorry for writting such a messy question!

Comment: @JordanT. If this is satisfactory, don’t forget to accept the answer, and upvote answers you find helpful.